# Symfony2 extract text from javascript to translation

Tags: javascript, symfony, translation

I have installed [BazingaJsTranslationBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle) in my Symfony2 project.

It works fine but is there a way to extract text from javascript file the way done in  **translation:extract** symfony2 command?

The text in javascript file looks like this:

```
Translator.trans("This is the text that I want to extract")
```

I do not want to go through adding keys in twig or php files to translate text in javascript files.

Here is the command that I use to extract text from php and twig files:

```
php app/console translation:extract en
--enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --dir=./src/ --output-dir=./app/Resources/translations
```

Answer (score 1):

You can by creating a custom extractor for the JS translations. That's done by implementing the [`Symfony\Component\Translation\Extractor\ExtractorInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/Translation/blob/master/Extractor/ExtractorInterface.php):

```
/**
 * Extracts translation messages from a template directory to the catalogue.
 * New found messages are injected to the catalogue using the prefix.
 *
 * @author Michel Salib <michelsalib@hotmail.com>
 */
interface ExtractorInterface
{
    /**
     * Extracts translation messages from a template directory to the catalogue.
     *
     * @param string           $directory The path to look into
     * @param MessageCatalogue $catalogue The catalogue
     */
    public function extract($directory, MessageCatalogue $catalogue);

    /**
     * Sets the prefix that should be used for new found messages.
     *
     * @param string $prefix The prefix
     */
    public function setPrefix($prefix);
}
```

> To make it usefull to others, it'll be even more awesome if you submitted your extractor to the BazingaJsTranslationBundles.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a PR for this in the main repository: https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle/pull/164